# How to get column number for regex match using VBA/Macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I want to get cell number like A:1 for every match found using regex and store it on sheet next to the current in same excel file. Is it possible to achieve in excel. As few of the examples I tried return match found true/false.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:="Custom ", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        aCell.Value = "Test"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

This is the sample I tried!!

Comment: Since aCell is a Range, you can use aCell.Column to get the Column Number

Comment: @gizlmeier  Thanks for this i'll try, and how will it put all result in new sheet !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        With ws
            Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:="Custom ", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = aCell.Address
            Else
                MsgBox "Not Found"
            End If
        End With
End Sub
```

if you want all the match try below

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With ws
            For i = 1 To lastrow
                If InStr(Range("B" & i), "Custom ") > 0 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Range("B" & i).Address
                End If
            Next i
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Karthik.. What is "B" which u have used inside Range .. I think its column name?

Comment: Hope you found the answer that you have asked. Kindly mark it as solution if you satisfy. Kindly modify the code above with iterating through columns